# Partition a file based on one column

Tags: shell-script, text-processing, awk

I have the following data set:

```
M1  1   1233
M2  1   3212
M3  1   55323
M4  1   4444233
M5  1   23444
M6  1   555333
M7  1   55567
M8  2   22224
M9  2   55566
M10 2   4567
M11 3   44242
M12 3   234234
M13 4   2233
M14 4   2442
M15 4   322352
M16 4   235242
M17 4   2324524
M18 5   232342
M19 6   2322523
M20 6   2332523
```

and I want to create an array based on values of the second column. I want to apply other commands in all lines that have `1` in the second column, after in lines that have `2` in the second column, and so on,
and to save these in different files, but I don't know how to do this. 
I tried to use a `while` command, but all my attempts failed.

The outputs of this code should be subsets of the original file in each index of the array; for example:

#### index i1

```
M1  1   1233
M2  1   3212
M3  1   55323
M4  1   4444233
M5  1   23444
M6  1   555333
M7  1   55567
```

#### index i2

```
M8  2   22224
M9  2   55566
M10 2   4567
```

and so on until

#### index i6

```
M19 6   2322523
M20 6   2332523
```

In these indexes, I want to apply other commands.

How can I do this in a shell script and/or awk?

Comment: You should specify the programming language.

Comment: Can be in a shell script or awk.

Comment: Please give a more complete minimal example - it's not clear whether you want to apply a command to each line in turn, or to apply a single command to the whole block of lines whose second column takes a particular value

Comment: I would like to apply a command to the whole block of lines whose second column takes a particular value.

Comment: This is very much an XY Problem. You've told us how you want to do something (`I want to create an array based on values of the second column  ... in these indexes, I want to apply other commands.`) but not what it is you want to do with the sets of input lines (are you trying to create shell arrays or awk arrays? what is an example of one of these "other commands"? What would the output be? etc.). So in answer to `Can you help me?` - I'm sorry but so far, no.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get the best results from awk:

```
awk '{ print > "index i"$2 }' < input
```

You can also do it purely in the shell:

```
while read a b c
do
        printf '%s\n' "$a $b $c" >> "index i$b"
done < input
```

The awk solution has these advantages:

- It will overwrite existing files. 
  The shell script will append to existing files. 
  (I suppose that might be what you want. 
  In that case,
  you can achieve it by using `>>` instead of `>` in the awk script.)
- The awk script preserves the spacing of the input file. 
  The shell script reduces multiple spaces to single spaces.
- For large data files, the awk script may be slightly faster.

Comment: For _huge_ data (many different values in the second column, you may want to start closing output files in the `awk` program, so that you don't run out of available file descriptors).

Comment: Yeah.  The OP doesn’t say that their input data are sorted /collated by that second column, but I guess it’s a plausible assumption.

Answer (score 0):

To add to G-Man's answer: **yes you can achieve the exact same result using only sh** (since this was the specification in your duplicate question [there](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1158265/create-an-array-in-data-file-while-the-value-in-a-specifc-column-is-constant/1158270), which I answered 9 hours prior to G-Man answer here).

There is a builtin `set` which allows you to assign values to `$1` `$2` and `$3` and so on. Here is a quote from the man page of bash (this also applies to sh):

***set [{ -options | +options | -- }] arg ...***

> The third use of the set command is to set the values of the shell's positional parameters to the specified args.  To change the positional parameters without
>               changing any options, use “--” as the first argument to set.  If no args are present, the set command will clear all the positional parameters (equivalent to
>               executing “shift $#”.)

So we can do:

```
set -f
while read ln; do
    set -- $ln
    printf '%s\n' "$ln" >> "index i"$2
done < input
set +f
```

In `set -- $ln`, `$ln` is split into fields and the nth field is assigned to the nth positional parameter.

The quote around `$ln` in the next line ensures the integrity of the content (preserving spacing etc.).

The `set -f` and `set +f` are there to prevent globbing characters like * and ? in the file from confusing `set`. Thanks to Scott for bringing this up.

Instead of `printf`, I originally used `echo`. But thanks to Scott's second comment (if an adversary changes a line to `echo`'s options like `-n`, `-e`, etc, then `echo` will get confused), `printf` is used instead to guard against that.

This shows sh is probably not an ideal choice for this sort of work. At least use bash which has regex support. But, it's doable if you try.

As to awk, well, it's not "slightly faster", but faster by an order of of magnitude if disk IO is not considered. So using awk is preferred.

Btw, I am sure you haven't heard of the saying "if two answers are one too many, then two questions are two too many".

> since I just said it ;)

But next time make a choice and stick to it so that we can all focus our effort there.

Comment: OK, your answer preserves whitespace.  But it fails if the input file contains any wildcard characters (e.g., ``?`` or ``*``).

Comment: Good point! (can't seem to upvote your comment ...) Didn't consider this since I didn't see any of those in the given data. But to be safe, I suppose it's sufficient to `set -f` before and `set +f` after?

Comment: I haven’t looked at it in depth, but, yes, that seems like it would work. Another issue is that your code would choke on an input line containing only `-n` — presumably that’s why G-Man’s answer uses `printf` instead of `echo` — but that should really never happen in a file that’s been described as having multiple columns.

Answer (score -1):

Command

```
  for i in `awk '{if(!seen[$2]++)print $2}' y.txt`;do awk -v i="$i" 'BEGIN {print "index i"i}$2==i {print $0}END {print "========================================"}' y.txt; done
```

output

```
index i1
M1  1   1233
M2  1   3212
M3  1   55323
M4  1   4444233
M5  1   23444
M6  1   555333
M7  1   55567
========================================
index i2
M8  2   22224
M9  2   55566
M10 2   4567
========================================
index i3
M11 3   44242
M12 3   234234
========================================
index i4
M13 4   2233
M14 4   2442
M15 4   322352
M16 4   235242
M17 4   2324524
========================================
index i5
M18 5   232342
========================================
index i6
M19 6   2322523
M20 6   2332523
========================================
```

Comment: Done completely by awk

Comment: (1) So, if there are *M* distinct values in the second column, you want to run ```awk``` on the entire input file *M* +1 times?!  (2) Ugh!  Backticks!  Ugh!